# Extracting a section of text from html using rvest

Tags: r

I am trying to extract specific references from *PubMed* pages like this one: [https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/35867413]. I'm using `XML` and `rvest`. Here's a simplified extract from a downloaded web page:

```
text = '<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en" > 
<div class="references" id="references">
<h4 class="refs-list-title">References to studies included in this review</h4>
<div class="refs-list">
<h5 class="refs-list-title">Ahn 2008</h5>
<h5 class="refs-list-title">Al‐Shehr 2020</h5>
<h4 class="refs-list-title">References to studies excluded from this review</h4>
<div class="refs-list">
<h5 class="refs-list-title">Smith 2020</h5>
</html>'

pubmed_page = read_html(text)
references = xml_find_all(pubmed_page, ".//div[@class='references']") 
xml_find_all(references, ".//h4[@class='refs-list-title']") %>%
  xml_text()
[1] "References to studies included in this review"  
[2] "References to studies excluded from this review"
```

What I want is to just get the first two references, so something like:

```
xml_?(references) %>% xml_text()
[1]Ahn 2008
[2]Al‐Shehr 2020
```

So the two lines of text at level h5 under the first h4.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific nature of what you are looking for. Probably try:

```
library(rvest)
read_html(text)%>%
  html_nodes('div.refs-list h5') %>%
  html_text()

[1] "Ahn 2008"      "Al-Shehr 2020" "Smith 2020"
```

Comment: Thanks, but that includes "Smith 2020", whereas I only want the first two.

Comment: @agbarnett as I stated in before the solution, there is no unique identifier for what you are looking for. Just select the first 2 elements of the resulting vector. Unless you give a unique id/class/attribute to those two that you want, there is no way to just capture them